# Invalid signature for signature method HMAC-SHA1

Tags: oauth, oauth-provider

I am using oauth 1.0 provider implementation to protect my api as security mechanism.

I am using [Oauth Test Client](http://term.ie/oauth/example/client.php) to request token, authorize and get access token and it is working quite fine. But I can not access my protected resources using it as it does not provide such facility.

So i tried to use [Netflix Client](http://developer.netflix.com/resources/OAuthTest) to generate calls for oauth provider. But when I try to run such calls they are not succeeded but give me **HTTP Status 401 - Invalid signature for signature method HMAC-SHA1**. I tried to generate signature manually and using some [Automatic Method](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/authentication/) but all ended in same error.

Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong? or could you please refer me to some good material or suggest any solution? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure it out? #bump

Comment: yeah i figured it out but it was a comlex thing to understand, I have moved to oauth 2.0, its mux simpler.

Comment: Can you share how you generated the OAuth signature? I'm stuck at Garmin OAuth because of this

Comment: Yea me too, I'm stuck with garmin auth, no luck so far :(

Comment: I am also stuck on garmin oauth